# How to delete Quickbook Invoice using SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, interop, quickbooks

We are using Interop.QBFC14 SDK to delete invoice.

```
IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionHelper.GetMsgSetRequest();
                
ITxnDel txnDelRq = requestMsgSet.AppendTxnDelRq();

txnDelRq.TxnDelType.SetValue(ENTxnDelType.tdtInvoice);

txnDelRq.TxnID.SetValue("<<InvoiceNo>>");
```

But the response from SDK is

> Object "[[InvoiceNo]]" specified in the request cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionHelper.GetMsgSetRequest();
            
ITxnDel txnDelRq = requestMsgSet.AppendTxnDelRq();

txnDelRq.TxnDelType.SetValue(ENTxnDelType.tdtInvoice);

txnDelRq.TxnID.SetValue(TxnID);

Pass TxnID
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).